# Could compression make gas colder not hotter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

In classical thermodynamics compression always makes gas hotter because of the mechanical work it inputs. However, if the particle density is too high, particles will become degenerate and obey the Fermi-Dirac statistics instead. Particles in highly degenerate fermi gas can possess very high kinetic energy, but the manifested temperature can be very low. So my question is if such quantum degeneracy can offset or even reverse the temperature rise due to kinetic energy increase.

The self gravity of the gas cloud is ignored. I know that extreme gravity of neutron stars can cause significant redshift in the emission spectrum, which makes the temperature measured in distant sites lower than the temperature measured inside. But that’s irrelevant to my question.

Comment: Do you mean adiabatic compression? You have two degrees of freedom, so you need to specify what quantity you are fixing during the compression (by default, I assumed entropy).

Comment: Apparently it must be adiabatic, otherwise the system can dump its heat to the environment.

Comment: The answer is no. Check out for example [Equation of State of an ideal Fermi Gas](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/link_gateway/1977ApJ...212..859B/doi:10.1086/155110), specifically section II-b) (the relevant answer for you is summarised in Figure 5).